# FFT (быстрое преобразование Фурье)

Tags: аудио, opensource, c++, qt

При работе со звуком возможно ли вычислить только часть звукового спектра, не вычисляя всю остальную? Если это возможно, то был бы рад ссылкам на движки, желательно Open Source.

Comment: Что значит часть спектра? Как это? А opensource fft -- "Fastest Fourier Transform in the West." www.fftw.org

Comment: Про этот вариант реализации реализацию - мне известно. Возникла проблема с интеграцией. Возможно ли получить часть спектра, то есть не вычислять все значения, а получить необходимый диапазон, в целях оптимизации.

Comment: Что значит "необходимый диапазон"? fft вычисляет значения в диапазоне от 0 до половины частоты дискретизации. Вам нужна часть значений? Берите часть. Если бы речь шла просто о DFT (дискретном преобразовании Фурье), то имело бы смысл заморачиваться на эту тему, а оптимизации fft, как мне кажется, сводят смысл операции на нет. Но разумеется, Вы можете сами посчитать DFT по нужной части спектра без всяких библиотек, просто я не уверен, что овчинка стоит выделки.

Comment: В целях оптимизации можно только уменьшить разрешение спектра, т.е. уменьшить число гармоник. Спектр будет строиться очень быстро на 100-200 гармониках, хотя, при этом, конечно теряется его точность. Выбирайте: скорость или детализация спектра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что Вы ищете это - [преобразование Герцеля](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%93%D1%91%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F). Разрешение спектра он не улучшит (оно зависит только от количества входных отсчётов), но можно посчитать на любой частоте.

Из бесплатных библиотек с этой функцией слышал о [spandsp](http://www.soft-switch.org/downloads/spandsp/), но сам не пробовал. Из проприетарных ИМХО лучшая это - [Intel Performance Primitives (IPP)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp)

Comment: Поддержу. Если задача - найти лучшее разложение по предварительно известному набору частот, то лучше использовать алгоритм Гёрцеля. Пример - распознавание сигналов DTMF в VoIP.

Answer (score 0):

Из опенсорса на ум приходит нещадно эксплуатируемая повсеместно [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). Получив из картинки, например, полуспектр, как бы так сказать, преобразованием косинусов, [Cosine Transform](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html#cv-dct), можно отфильтровать ненужные частоты (верхний левый пиксель результата преобразования отвечает за самую низкую частоту, остальные - слева направо по возрастанию частоты)

Да и ещё [здесь пишут о том, как OpenCV с Qt интегрировать](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11655-OpenCV-integration)

Comment: Благодарю, но как в OpenCV работать со звуком?

Comment: ok, виноват, не обратил внимание на главное условие :) Но указанная функция работает и с одномерным массивом, так что из "картинки" лёгким движением делаем звук

Answer (score 0):

FFTW - библиотека, делающая только преобразование Фурье. Но делает она это очень быстро. В настройках я не копался, но вполне возможно, что ее можно настроить для задачи. Но я бы не стал, так как все равно делается это очень быстро.

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать `Audio Processing + FFT` в `GNU Octave`.